# Function calls are not supported in decorators

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am facing an issue while ng build --prod:

Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'Ui' was called in 'initialState'

```
export const initialState: AppState = {
   userAisles: null,
   userItems: null,
   userLists: null,
   userShops: null,
   ui: new Ui(),
   config: new Config(),
};
```

and my Ui class:

```
export class Ui {
   loading: false;
   itemsOrder = 'name';
   itemsOrderSense = 'ASC';
   listsOrder = 'date';
   listsOrderSense = 'ASC';
   listsConsultOrder = 'name';
   listsConsultOrderSense = 'ASC';
   history: string = null;
   resolved = false;

   constructor(values: Object = {}) {
      return Object.assign(this, values);
   }
}
```

If I hardcode the Ui class in initialState, it works and then complains about Config class, so the problem is there. I don't find any solution to get rid of the compiling error message.

Here's my config:

```
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^6.1.0",
    "angular-hammer": "^2.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "font-awesome": "~4.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "ng2-dragula": "^2.0.2",
    "ngx-facebook": "^2.4.0",
    "primeng": "^6.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: How do you import Config in the file where you're exporting initialState?

Comment: please add the error itself and the code the error points to.

Answer (score 0):

can you use a factory method?
instead of calling `new Ui()` or `new Config()` use a function that returns a new Ui or a new Config object like this:

```
export const uiFactory(){
   return new Ui();
}

export const configFactory(){
   return new Config();
}

export const initialState: AppState = {
   userAisles: null,
   userItems: null,
   userLists: null,
   userShops: null,
   ui: uiFactory,
   config: configFactory
};
```

or will they not be called?

or just do

```
const config = new Config();
{.... config: config .....}
```

cause initialState will be binded only once.